# Creating a unique modal service

Tags: angular

I've created a service that defines several `Observables` for determining which modal a calling component can request:

```
@Injectable()
export class DialogService {

  areYouSureDialog$: Subject<IAreYouSureDialog> = new Subject<IAreYouSureDialog>();
  confirmWithCommentDialog$: Subject<IConfirmWithCommentDialog> = new Subject<IConfirmWithCommentDialog>();

  showAreYouSureDialog = (settings: IAreYouSureDialog) => {
    this.areYouSureDialog$.next(settings);
  };
}
```

I've placed the actual components in the `app.component.html` file and this component subscribes for the changes and displays the modal if it's triggered:

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="(dialogService.areYouSureDialog$ | async) as d">
    <confirm-yes-no-dialog
      *ngIf="d?.show"
      [confirmTitle]="d.confirmTitle"
      [confirmMessage]="d.confirmMessage"
      [disableHide]="d.disableHide"
      [yesLabel]="d.yesLabel"
      [noLabel]="d.noLabel"
      [cancel]="d.cancel"
      [cancelLabel]="d.cancelLabel"
      (confirmClosed)="d.show = false; d.onConfirmClosed($event)"
    >
    </confirm-yes-no-dialog>
  </ng-container>
```

Because the above is defined in the `app.component.html`, basically the first component in the application, this means that even if I define the `DialogService` as a `providers: [DialogService]`, all of it's children gain access to the same service. See Angulars explanation of this [here](https://docs.angular.lat/guide/singleton-services#singleton-services)

The problem raised to me is that any component can gain access to the contents of the object passed to the `DialogService` by subscribing to it, which negates the benefit of the service itself, though I'm not convinced of this.

Even if I instead define the service as part of a `SharedModule` and inject that module into whereever needs it, the data is still shared and subscribable.

Is there a way to allow the modals to be called via a service but hide/obfuscate the data being passed so other components can't see it?

I'm open to other suggestions to this end but I don't want an npm package for this.